# Is it possible to escape Json string using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

Hi I Have the need to escape a json string and I think
using Newtonsoft.Json does the trick however

```
var unescapedString=System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(MyObject);
var escapedJsonString = JsonConvert.ToString(unescapedString);//Newtonsoft.Json
```

How can I do the same (escape a json string) using System.Text.Json?

Comment: Hi not sure why this has been closed the link provided does not offer a solution that works

Comment: `JsonConvert.ToString()` serializes the string as a JSON string primitive, so you are actually just double-serializing your `MyObject`.  Thus in System.Text.Json you can do `var escapedJsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(unescapedString);`.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does all clear now

Comment: My guess was `JsonValue.Create(unescapedString)?.ToJsonString()` but `JsonSerializer.Serialize(unescapedString)` looks better.